# Trimming specific line from .txt files

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a large number of text (.txt) files where I need to trim the first line. The file looks similar to this:

```
siteID:8741234DB
Source location: XXXXXXX
Backup Information: XXXXXX
SourceLocation: 4445656DB
```

I'm simply trying to remove the "**DB**" from the end of line 1.

I'm preferably trying to find the simplest solution via batch or powershell. Most solutions I've come across move the entire line, but as I mentioned I only need to ***trim the end of the first line***. As an instance of "DB" may occur again in the file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the files are not too large, you can rely on `Get-Content` to read the files and `Set-Content` to update/rewrite the files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path FilePath\*.txt | Foreach-Object {
    if ((Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -TotalCount 1) -match 'DB$') { # check for DB at end of first line
        $file = Get-Content $_.FullName # read file into array
        $file[0] = $file[0].TrimEnd('DB') # update first line of array
        $file | Set-Content $_.FullName # write array to file
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try a little harder not to directly answer code requests, as those are not what this site is here for. You could have offered a comment with links if necessary, or found a duplicate for this type of task, _(which the OP could have further adapted themselves as necessary)_.

Comment: @Compo, I do agree. But it does appear that the OP did research and did not find an answer. It could be that searching with the right combination of wording proved difficult.

Comment: It appears to me, that the OP has not provided any information whatsoever to show that they've attempted anything. Just saying they've looked does not constitute a reasonable attempt at the task, and no code, especially without any supporting information to show how it fails, even less so. as I said, there are certainly plenty of PowerShell coded answers on this site which cycle through files, get the content of each and manipulate one or more lines within them. So each part of your answer can be individually researched from existing search facility questions and answers.